# Angular 16 website that searches and displays results. Also ability to modify the data

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I'm asking for some tips from more experienced developers.
Any help is appreciated.

Overview:  Front-end (Angular) + Back-end (C#) you can disregard the back-end for now.

[image: Mock website]

**Description of what the website is supposed to do:**

1. Search for a customer. So you enter a name/number. This makes a call to a back-end server. For now, let i be a local JSON file since I haven't built the back-end yet.
   So the only thing you see when you enter the page is "Search for information" and the input field and button.
2. Once I press the search button and get a hit a table should be loaded below the search bar containing the results of my search. The table should only appear if I get a hit.
   If not, there should be empty space below the search bar.
3. I can interact with the search results to get details or modify (change) the data.
4. The "Details/Modify" section will be located below the Results table.

That's basically it.

So my question to you Angular developers out there is, **how do I structure the website?**

With structure I mean, how many components, services, what kind of binding etc.
Which components should be nested?

If there's something I've missed, please ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use smart/dumb components

You have a simple 1 feature customer crud (create-read-update-delete) requirement.

This leads to 1 smart component (`customer-crud.component.ts`) which will be the page as shown in the image.

This smart component injects the service that gets the data and passes this data to the child components. The dumb ui components take input and outputs events when the user types/clicks.

```
customer-feature/
  customer-crud.component.ts // smart component gets data from service, passes to children and handles child events
  customer.service.ts // get customers (with search), create, update, delete methods
  ui/
    search.component.ts // output's search string
    customer-table.component.ts // input list of customers, output `details` and `change` events
    customer-detail.component.ts // input customer, presentational only
    customer-form.component.ts // optional input customer (for edit), output created / updated customer
```

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so77229951-structure)

Comment: Thanks a lot, just some things I need to get clarified, if it's OK. 
I'm trying to understand the HTML . 

So if I understand the structure it's basically:

customer-crud and customer.service are the parents and the UI folder holds the children?

search.component is the going to be displayed first? The HTML I mean.

Comment: `customer-crud.component.ts` is the parent, `customer.service.ts` is an injectable service. I'll create a stackblitz with it

Comment: wow thats great thanks!

Comment: @Moe-Doe I've added a stackblitz and tried to simulate interaction with a real backend as much as possible. Still needs error handling, customer create and delete but it gives a good idea of what canonical angular application looks like. One of the benefits of angular is if you get this pattern you'll see it if you have to jump into someone else's angular app. Note this uses latest v16 angular with signals and standalone components. v17 will introduce new syntax to replace ngFor etc.

Comment: Thanks alot Andrew, you did more than I can imagine! Wish there was some kind of reward system here.